# Filtering calendar view request in Microsoft Graph API by categories

Tags: events, microsoft-graph-api, categories

I need get from Graph API events without any category or havn't specific category
So, when I send:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2024-01-05T12:32:50.095Z&endDateTime=2024-01-31T12:32:50.095Z&$filter=not (categories/any(x:x eq 'MySyncJob'))
```

I get response

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
        "message": "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed."
    }
}
```

But request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2024-01-05T12:32:50.095Z&endDateTime=2024-01-31T12:32:50.095Z&$filter=categories/any(x:x eq 'MySyncJob')
```

and

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2024-01-05T12:32:50.095Z&endDateTime=2024-01-31T12:32:50.095Z&$filter=categories/any(x:x ne 'MySyncJob')
```

working well...

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `calendarView` endpoint supports only filtering by one category

```
/v1.0/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2024-01-05T12:32:50.095Z&endDateTime=2024-01-31T12:32:50.095Z&$filter=categories/any(x:x eq 'MySyncJob')
```

Based on OData specification, you should be able to get events without categories by either

```
/v1.0/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2024-01-05T12:32:50.095Z&endDateTime=2024-01-31T12:32:50.095Z&$filter=not(categories/any())
```

or

```
/v1.0/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2024-01-05T12:32:50.095Z&endDateTime=2024-01-31T12:32:50.095Z&$filter=categories/$count eq 0
```

But it's not supported and I don't expect that they will improve/fix it.

For now, only solution is to get all event from the range and filter them on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there might be an issue with the `not` operator in your request. Try using the `ne` (not equal) operator to exclude the specific category. Here's an adjusted version:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2024-01-05T12:32:50.095Z&endDateTime=2024-01-31T12:32:50.095Z&$filter=categories/any(x:x ne 'MySyncJob')
```

This should filter out events with the `MySyncJob` category.

Comment: You right, this work, but not as I need. This not return event without any category...